# HTML5: Centered absolute layout fixed size element across mobile and desktop

Tags: css, html, viewport, mobile-website

I am creating an HTML5 game, in a 4:3 'viewport', in which elements are positioned absolutely (as I want to use 'world coordinates').

Rather than having different layouts for different devices I would like to be able to develop it with a single layout. I would like to have a single 4:3 container element, centred on a black background.

On large screens  (table, desktop) I would like it to hit a maximum physical size (e.g. 20cm by 15cm). On mobile screens, I would like it to zoom-to-fit with no overflow at any orientation (which will encourage people to flip to landscape).

Is this possible? I've been messing around with the viewport tag, but getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I'm looking for in the article [Case Study: Auto-Resizing HTML5 Games](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/gopherwoord-studios-resizing-html5-games/)

```
 and here's what I made, based on that:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mcintyre321/hkLLqzr1/

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned items are positioned based on X,Y from the known (left) corner of the page.  So if you're in a situation where that page size could change, your option for re-positioning those items proportionately is going to involve a boatload of javascript likely.  You'll have to evaluate that page size, determine your proportions for margins and padding of your absolutely positioned elements, and then re-position them as needed.

Not seeing code or a screenshot, it's impossible to know exactly what you're trying to do.  The big question to ask yourself is WHY?  Do you REALLY need absolute positioning, or is this simply a way to avoid the intricacies of relatively position and the box model?  My personal rule of thumb is that an item is only absolutely positioned if it has to float over or intersect another container, and there are even alternatives to most of those situations.  Responsive design has come a long, long way of late, and it's likely that using a mix of javascript, css, and media queries you could achieve your goal.

Comment: The elements are to be positioned absolutely within the fixed size viewport element. I'll make the question more clear, thanks.

Comment: That's just it-- you can position things quite precisely without having to go absolute and still achieve what you're trying to accomplish.  I get that things have to be precise, but there's an army of UI guys doing pixel-perfect relative layouts everyday...it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your input, and apologies if I didn't make what I was after clear enough. In the end I've found an article which has solved my problem (admittedly using an onresize event and js, rather than an elegant tag of some kind)